# RequestDispatcher not working with Filter

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, requestdispatcher

I am having a filter at a location (/dir/store_image/*).

When I am redirecting to it through a RequestDispatcher its not working.

But its working fine with response.sendRedirect.

With requestDispatcher the output is - the requested resource is not available.

The example code -

```
String path = req.getRequestURI() ;

path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, path.length());

path = "../dir/store_image/" + path;

/* Not working
  RequestDispatcher request_Dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher(path);
  request_Dispatcher.forward(request,response);*/

//Working

HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.sendRedirect(path);
```

The filter mapping -

(from StoreImageA i am forwarding to StoreImage)

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StoreImage</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/dir/store_image/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StoreImageA</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/store_image/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Then the path was plain wrong. URL != resourcepath.

Comment: nope, you cannot get requestDispatcher to work which forwards to a url having a filter.

Comment: Uh, request dispatcher doesn't take URL. It expects a resource path but you passed an URL. Hence my hint URL != resourcepath. The send redirect is the only who takes an URL (for the obvious reason that it is performed client side instead of server side).

Comment: i tested when there was no filter at the forward url, and request dispatcher worked just fine. With a filter it could not forward.

Comment: Then you've a different problem than asked here.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya - Can you show us the filter?